# How does Uni<T> works in Quarkus

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, quarkus, mutiny

I am trying to understand the behavior of Uni in Quarkus framework, after checking out their official tutorial [getting started with async guide](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/main/getting-started-async).
In the service method I have made the following changes

```
package org.acme.getting.started.async;

import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;

import io.smallrye.mutiny.Uni;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


@ApplicationScoped
public class GreetingService {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, r -> {
        return new Thread(r, "CUSTOM_TASK_EXECUTION_THREAD");
    });


    public Uni<String> greeting(String name) {
        System.out.println("greeting Executing on Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Uni.createFrom().item(ioSimulation(name))
                .emitOn(executor);//Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor()
    }

    public String ioSimulation(String param){
        System.out.println("ioSimulation Executing on Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "hello "+param;

    }

}
```

Then I have tested the /greeting/{name} resource, the execution was not async at all, in fact it executed all related methods within the same thread and in synchronous manner.

then what would be the difference between

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    public Uni<String> greeting(@PathParam String name) {
    }
```

and

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/greeting/{name}")
    public String greeting(@PathParam String name) {
    }
```

and how is it asynchronous?  please help me to understand it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `Uni.createFrom().item(ioSimulation(name))`. You synchronously call `ioSimulation` before the `Uni` is created.

You should at least use the `Supplier` variant: `Uni.createFrom().item(() -> ioSimulation(name))`. That should help.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @Ladicek answer, I believe you want to use `runSubscriptionOn` and not `emitOn`. See https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/emit-subscription as reference.

Comment: Good point! The difference between `subscribeOn` / `observeOn` in RxJava, as well as `emitOn` /  `runSubscriptionOn` in Mutiny, is one of the most confusing parts of these libraries for me.

Comment: thanks for the link, it truly helped me. the main problem is there is not many resources out there to understand in depth.

Comment: Check the mutiny documentation. It's not perfect, but provide a good overview (Totally biased opinion here :-)). If there are uncovered subjects, open issues. We will be very happy to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

both the answers above are correct. I made some changes in service class and `ioSimulation(String param)` method was offloaded to the custom thread pool. The final solution is given below

```
public class GreetingService {

    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new NameableThreadFactory("CUSTOM_TASK_EXECUTION_THREAD");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, threadFactory);

    public Uni<String> greeting(String name) {
        System.out.println("greeting Executing on Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return Uni.createFrom().item(()->ioSimulation(name))
                .runSubscriptionOn(executor);//Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor()
    }


    public String ioSimulation(String param){
        System.out.println("ioSimulation Executing on Thread "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(8000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "hello "+param;

    }
}
```

--**update**--

`emitOn(Executor executor)` will also works asynchronously if you pass `supplier` in `item` method but the approach is slightly different, I have figured that while experimenting with `Uni`, [this](https://github.com/arkaprovob/quarkus-mutiny.git) is my repo, incase if anyone is interested.